# WordPress Contextual Hlp

Tags: wordpress

Sorry for the "Hlp" in the title - It seems that the forum has listed "Help" as a restricted word.

Anyway, I wonder if someone can help me? Ive been searching for a while to no avail.

In the WordPress contextual help tab, I have created my own custom items - great!

I want to unset the default WordPress help items (overview/ navigation/ layout/ content) but I cannot seem to find a code snippet.

Appreciate any advice.

Thank you

Comment: Why do people vote down, then offer no constructive advice as to why they voted down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to find the below code which removes the default help tabs as I wanted.

```
add_action('admin_head', 'remove_default_tabs');
function remove_default_tabs() {
    $screen = get_current_screen();
    $screen->remove_help_tabs();
}
```